# Is there a working jbpm3 tutorial?

Tags: java, jboss, jbpm

i'm searching desperately for a working tutorial on how i can install jbpm3 and successfully
run the demo websale process from the jbpm-console.

With jbpm 3.2.9 (and jboss 5.0.1 or 4.2.3, with hypersonic) i am able to log into the jbpm console, but when I try to create and evaluate the *Create new web sale order* task, i get the following exceptions:

Error
Error completing task: An exception of type "org.jbpm.graph.def.DelegationException" was thrown. The message is: no applicable exception handler found
Closing the database context failed: An exception of type org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException was thrown, with the message: Cannot open connection

Does someone know an jbpm3 tutorial which just works?

Answer (score 0):

ok it seens that it is a problem concerning the hsqldb's missing support for two phase commit transactions. my own processes runned fine as long as i didnt use any timers.
the solution would be to install another db, for example postgres.

Comment: You could try using the last version of HSQLdb (2.2) which has limited transaction isolation, including two phase locking: see [here](http://hsqldb.org/web/features200.html).